# UITableView resizing rows problem

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hope to get solution to this problem. I have been stuck on it since a long time now.

I have a a tableView which has custom labels drawn upon the cell using CGRect. I receive the data from a web service in arrays. Initially i display a line of data on the cells. When the user selects a cell, I call reloadsRowAtIndexPath to increase the height of selected row. In the process, cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called again. I keep track of this by a flag, and when cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called again, I display the two more lines of data from arrays, on the cell.

What i am getting is all overlapping data on one other. I tried to remove already placed labels in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but to no avail.

Please help me on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, when the selected row height needs to increase, do you create a new UITableViewCell object or change an already allocated one?

Please can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code to help track this down?